# KieSession no output and no syntax error

Tags: drools, kie

```
    KieBaseModel kieBaseModel = kieModuleModel.newKieBaseModel("TEST");
    kieBaseModel.setDefault(true);
    kieBaseModel.addPackage("com.dynamicservice");
    kieBaseModel.newKieSessionModel("DefaultSession")
                .setDefault(true);
    kfs.writeKModuleXML(kieModuleModel.toXML());

    KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);
    KieModule kModule=kb.getKieModule();
    kr.addKieModule(kModule);
    kb.buildAll(); // kieModule is automatically deployed to KieRepository if successfully built
```

If I try to build a KieSession with the name "DefaultSession", there will no output but no syntactic error either. Where is the problem?

Comment: What are you expecting to see? How to know what the problem is if we don't know your expectations?

Comment: thanks for your comment.I find that the problem is package name. It doesn`t work and i don`t know why.could you give me some advice? I can`t find a direction.